# How do I create a hinged wing?

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, bones

So I'm planning this semi-photorealistic animation involving a flying ship, some green miles, and a supervoid as special effects, and some of the many models that are going to need to be created are:

Chen, a Nekomata from the Touhou Project (Perfect Cherry Blossom.)
A Parasect from Pokémon.
Several angels with wings.

I'm trying to figure out how to would a hinged wing actually work in Blender? For that matter, should wings, tails or other tentacular appendages be animated through bones, or through simple physical rotation?

It's only been laid out on paper, and the entire project's pretty much ground to a halt because I can't seem to remember how to parent a mesh to an armature.
(Also, feel free to submit some blends to help me out here.)
Thanks, Nefer007 (Anyone who responds gets to be mentioned in the credits!)

Comment: Others may find it useful for you to state your artistic style for your project.  Photo Realistic or Cartoon for example.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time (and edit the title to reflect that question).

Comment: Okay, here you go on a silver platter... one question on one question.

Comment: are the wings on a ship, or like an angel or somehting?

Comment: Both: look up Cyodrake's Gaze online for the ship's wings, and the angel wings are...well...angel wings.

Comment: P.S. If that was you that upvoted the answer, @RadishoftheOpera, oh my god thank you I finally leveled up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For Tails consider a Armature a Spline Constraint, employing curves, which can provide the smooth visuals.  That is just a starter.
- Armatures are suggested for Wings.  Thus you have control over the flapping motion. I assume you will need that control.
- You stated [I can't seem to remember how ..].  Consider a video website for tutorials. You may want to search .. Blender Tutorial Spline Constraint.
- Once some of the basics are there you can consider hundreds of subtleties.

Comment: Umm... I stated what? I've also been experimenting with all the objects, and the only things under my Armatures tab are Single Bone, Rigify Human, and Rigify Pichipoy Human.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to rig wings as well. I have all of the bones in the right wing with a "copy rotation" modifier copying the rotation of the bone I have selected in the image.[image: wing rig]

Every one of the teal bones have the copy rotation modifier, and have the target set to the right wing armature, and the bone set to the bone selected in the picture. I also clicked 'offset,' allowing me to edit the wing manually. Also, don't forget to set the 'space' to 'local space <-> local space'. Then, I have the left wing bones copying their right wing counterparts.